# Process list into separate lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Have:

```
my_list = [([9, 1, 4], ['b', 'j', 'k']), ([8, 5, 9], ['m', 't', 'y']), ([6, 2, 0], ['p', 'q', 'r'])]
```

Want (in sequence order):

```
number_list = [9, 1, 4, 8, 5, 9, 6, 2, 0]
letter_list = ['b', 'j', 'k', 'm', 't', 'y', 'p', 'q', 'r']
```

Obvious solution is:

```
for data in my_list:

    try:
        number_list += data[0]
        letter_list += data[1]
    except:
        number_list = data[0]
        letter_list = data[1]

print number_list
print letter_list

> [9, 1, 4, 8, 5, 9, 6, 2, 0]
> ['b', 'j', 'k', 'm', 't', 'y', 'p', 'q', 'r']
```

Is there a better and/or faster way to achieve this - possibly with a list comprehension?

Comment: Your "obvious" solution will change `my_list`. When you write `number_list = data[0]` you don't get a copy of the list in `data[0]` but a reference.

Comment: Didn't know that.  How do you get a copy of the list?

Comment: You'll get a copy with `number_list = data[0][:]` or by using [`copy.copy`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy) or in the case of nested structures [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a, b = [list(chain.from_iterable(x)) for x in zip(*my_list)]
>>> a
[9, 1, 4, 8, 5, 9, 6, 2, 0]
>>> b
['b', 'j', 'k', 'm', 't', 'y', 'p', 'q', 'r']
```

Comment: This works great until one day `my_list` is empty and you get a `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`.

Comment: Use try-except to address this problem.